# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: installation

Attempting to install Drupal 7.16 (also attempted 7.12) onto my local machine, I get the following error at the database stage.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Looking at the Drupal database with PHPMyAdmin, I see the "variables" table is created, together two columns; that is all that gets created prior to the error.

I can't find a single solution to this.

***EDIT***

Solved - found the drupal installation script andreverted the mysql engine back to MyISAM